# Tkinter image_create performance when inserting image into text box

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm building a Python (3.7.4) app to display items from a text database of vendor manuals. One of the functions is to display a list of "item names" from the database for each manual (aka "product"). I'm using a Tkinter scrolled text box widget for this function and simply building rows with item names with tabs to separate them. I would like to insert a small icon (16x20 pixels) in front of each item name, and have successfully done so using the code below. The problem I am having is that for large manuals in the database (e.g., 10K+ item names) I take a significant performance hit from the image_create function. Without inserting the images, displaying the list of item names is almost instantaneous for 10K item names. With inserting the images, it may take upwards of 10-12 seconds.

Any suggestions on how to improve performance? I've even looked into creating a "image" font using FontForge, but would prefer not to go that route if possible.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Per Bryan Oakley's request, I have attached executable code here. If you un-comment the following lines:

```
tabContents_text.image_create("current", image=open_book_image)
```

you will see the difference in performance.

Link to the png file is [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u4ZbqCRnnIso35NtJqncYaSupZPhncwY)

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

win = tk.Tk()
frame1 = tk.Frame(master = win)
frame1.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
win.state('zoomed')
tabContents_text = tkst.ScrolledText(frame1, cursor="arrow", wrap="none", tabs=150, font=('helvetica', 10, 'normal'))
tabContents_text.pack(side='top')
open_book_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:\\Users\\rhkea\\Downloads\\document_icon.png")
product_item_list=[]
for i in range(10000):
    product_item_list.append("Item" + str(i).zfill(5))
col_count=4
row_count=2500
row_remain=0
tabContents_text.delete("1.0", "end")
row = 0
item = 0

while row < row_count:
    col = 0
    while col < col_count:
#        tabContents_text.image_create("current", image=open_book_image)
        tabContents_text.insert("end", product_item_list[item] + '\t')
        col += 1
        item += 1
    tabContents_text.insert("end", "\n")
    row += 1

col = 0
while col < row_remain:
#    tabContents_text.image_create("current", image=open_book_image)
    tabContents_text.insert("end", product_item_list[item] + '\t')
    col += 1
    item += 1
tabContents_text.insert("end", "\n")

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: It would help if you could create code we can run. For example, instead of reading from a database you could create a loop which creates 10,000 items.

Comment: You can use __page__ concept to display the items, i.e. divide the items into groups, each group contains certain amount of items.  Load one group of item each time.

Comment: Bryan - I added simple executable code to the post along with a link to the .png image. If you un-comment the image_create statements you'll hopefully see the performance difference I'm talking about. Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to post the same code twice, it just makes the question more confusing.

Comment: Got it - removed original code snippet. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaly,I think there is no way to have a better performance.But you can use `.update()` 
 to show the image right away instead of blocking it in your code.

*I don't know what's the purpose of second `while` loop*

You can try this code,it will continue to load the image after you run it:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.scrolledtext as tkst

win = tk.Tk()
frame1 = tk.Frame(master = win)
frame1.pack(fill='both', expand='yes')
win.state('zoomed')
tabContents_text = tkst.ScrolledText(frame1, cursor="arrow", wrap="none", tabs=150, font=('helvetica', 10, 'normal'))
tabContents_text.pack(side='top')
open_book_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="document_icon.png")
product_item_list=[]
for i in range(10000):
    product_item_list.append("Item" + str(i).zfill(5))
col_count=4
row_count=2500
row_remain=0
tabContents_text.delete("1.0", "end")
row = 0
item = 0

try:
    while row < row_count:
        col = 0
        while col < col_count:
            tabContents_text.image_create("end", image=open_book_image) # It's "end" instead of current.
            tabContents_text.insert("end", product_item_list[item] + '\t')
            win.update() # update right away.
            col += 1
            item += 1
        tabContents_text.insert("end", "\n")
        win.update()
        row += 1

    col = 0
    # This while loop seems that it will create two empty lines
    while col < row_remain:
        tabContents_text.image_create("current", image=open_book_image)
        tabContents_text.insert("end", product_item_list[item] + '\t')
        win.update()
        col += 1
        item += 1
    tabContents_text.insert("end", "\n")

except BaseException: # Catch the raised exception when you close the window if it doesn't load image completely.
    pass

except Exception as e:
    print(e.args)


win.mainloop()
```

Maybe use `.after()` is also OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the image and the text into a single `Label` and then use `.window_create(...)` to insert into the `Text` box:

```
font = tabContents_text.cget('font') # get the Text font
for i in range(len(product_item_list)):
    # create label with both image and text
    lbl = tk.Label(tabContents_text, text=product_item_list[i]+'\t',
                   image=open_book_image, compound='left',
                   bg='white', font=font)
    # insert the label into text box
    tabContents_text.window_create('end', window=lbl)
    # insert line break after showing 'col_count' items
    if i%col_count == col_count-1:
        tabContents_text.insert('end', '\n')
```

It can reduce the total items inserted into text box by half.